# How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, r

I have a LaTeX table generated like this,

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\hline
1 & 181.21 & 169.01 & 130.03 & 135.93 & 142.31 & 108.11 \\ 
2 & 106.80 & 130.71 & 186.43 & 126.46 & 167.28 & 137.91 \\ 
3 & 162.69 & 198.98 & 188.33 & 184.30 & 147.02 & 197.38 \\ 
4 & 132.42 & 150.50 & 148.69 & 134.31 & 129.52 & 172.72 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

but when i compile it in MiKTeX I am getting the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin
          {table}[ht]
? 
Process interrupted by user
```

I want a table generated from this i am compiling under pdfTeX. I am using LaTeX for first time, can anyone please give a suggestion?

Comment: If your error message really says that it occurs on line 1, then you need to embed the table into an actual document, with a document class etc.  Also, if you really compiled with pdftex and not pdflatex, that's another problem.  See [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693)

Comment: table is a `LaTeX` environment so it won't be recognized by `pdftex`. Are you sure you want to use Plain TeX?

Comment: The table compiles for me. Could you enter the entire tex file?

Comment: This is the entire tex file I have...I have tried to compile it using pdfLaTex too but it did not work...where is the table generated for you @DJP ?

Comment: And also please tell me the procedure you are compiling?

Comment: If you are using `pdflatex`, you need to add `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` just before `\begin{table}`, and `\end{document}` right after `\end{table}`.

Comment: And if that's the whole document, it makes little sense to have the `table` environment, you should just have the the part from  `\begin{tabular}` to `\end{tabular}`. How was the code generated?

Comment: @Gonzalo Thank u tables are generated now...@Alan the code is generated from r

Comment: @alex If you are using `xtable` in R you can set `floating=FALSE` to eliminate the `\begin{table}` `\end{table}` code.  This might be preferable if you are not using LaTeX to write your entire document.

Comment: And don't use the `center` environment here but `\centering`!

Comment: @Martin: in this case it doesn't matter. He has no caption ...

Comment: Just read the friendly manual.

Comment: @Herbert: But `center` still adds some vertical white space which will change the distance to the surrounding text (if any), doesn't it?

Comment: @Martin unfortunately this is the default for floating tables generated by the R `xtable` package.  It's overridable, but there's no good way to automatically replace the `center` environment with `\centering`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You should probably turn this into an answer as the table works fine once you add those three things.

Comment: @Martin, sure as the caption already does itself, if present.

Comment: @Peter I've taken the opportunity to turn this question into a mini tutorial on creating tables in R.

Comment: [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since you are generating the table from R, I'll assume that you are using R's `xtable` package to generate the table.  This package has some deficiencies, but it is still quite usable.

Here's a sample R session showing how to use the package.

**R-session**

```r
data(tli)
## Demonstrate aov
 ## Taken from help(aov) in R 1.1.1
 ## From Venables and Ripley (1997) p.210.
 N <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0)
 P <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
 K <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
 yield <- c(49.5,62.8,46.8,57.0,59.8,58.5,55.5,56.0,62.8,55.8,69.5,55.0,
+            62.0,48.8,45.5,44.2,52.0,51.5,49.8,48.8,57.2,59.0,53.2,56.0)
 npk <- data.frame(block=gl(6,4), N=factor(N), P=factor(P), K=factor(K), yield=yield)
 npk.aov <- aov(yield ~ block + N*P*K, npk)
 op <- options(contrasts=c("contr.helmert", "contr.treatment"))
 npk.aovE <- aov(yield ~  N*P*K + Error(block), npk)
 options(op)
```

**Using xtable to produce the table**

```
## Standard xtable use
print(xtable(summary(npk.aov)))

% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Fri Aug 12 16:00:48 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
  \hline
 & Df & Sum Sq & Mean Sq & F value & Pr($>$F) \\ 
  \hline
block       & 5 & 343.29 & 68.66 & 4.45 & 0.0159 \\ 
  N           & 1 & 189.28 & 189.28 & 12.26 & 0.0044 \\ 
  P           & 1 & 8.40 & 8.40 & 0.54 & 0.4749 \\ 
  K           & 1 & 95.20 & 95.20 & 6.17 & 0.0288 \\ 
  N:P         & 1 & 21.28 & 21.28 & 1.38 & 0.2632 \\ 
  N:K         & 1 & 33.13 & 33.13 & 2.15 & 0.1686 \\ 
  P:K         & 1 & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.03 & 0.8628 \\ 
  Residuals   & 12 & 185.29 & 15.44 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The output of this command is a *fragment* of LaTeX code, not a complete working document. It is designed to be cut and pasted into an existing LaTeX document.  This is why you got the error that you got. Minimally, the document should look like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

And you would insert your table code in the `...` spot.  You then compile this with `pdflatex`.

This produces the following table:

[image: output of code]

### Problems with the standard xtable output

There are a number of problems with the standard `xtable` output.

1. It generates a floating `{table}` environment
2. It encloses the `tabular` in a `{center}` environment
3. It uses standard `\hline` as a separator

Although the floating table environment is useful when you are including the table into a larger LaTeX document, if you are generating a single table, it's not necessary. Furthermore, as a consequence of the floating environment, `xtable` encloses the table in a `{center}` environment, which leaves too much extra space between the table and other elements of your document.  Finally, it uses `\hline` for the table rules, which leads to a cramped looking table.

Most of these problems are solvable, although with some loss of auto-generation.

The first two problems are connected. The `print.xtable` function has two arguments, one to say whether the table should be floating or not, and another to define the environment to wrap the table in.  So we can modify our initial command to print the table in the following way to suppress both of these:

```r
## Revised R print command
print(xtable(summary(npk.aov)),floating=FALSE,latex.environments=NULL)
```

This produces the following LaTeX code:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Fri Aug 12 16:29:29 2011
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
  \hline
 & Df & Sum Sq & Mean Sq & F value & Pr($>$F) \\ 
  \hline
block       & 5 & 343.29 & 68.66 & 4.45 & 0.0159 \\ 
  N           & 1 & 189.28 & 189.28 & 12.26 & 0.0044 \\ 
  P           & 1 & 8.40 & 8.40 & 0.54 & 0.4749 \\ 
  K           & 1 & 95.20 & 95.20 & 6.17 & 0.0288 \\ 
  N:P         & 1 & 21.28 & 21.28 & 1.38 & 0.2632 \\ 
  N:K         & 1 & 33.13 & 33.13 & 2.15 & 0.1686 \\ 
  P:K         & 1 & 0.48 & 0.48 & 0.03 & 0.8628 \\ 
  Residuals   & 12 & 185.29 & 15.44 &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
```

If you have need for the table to float, then you should eliminate the `floating=FALSE` argument from the command, but leave the `latex.environments=NULL`.

However, this still leaves us with the cramped looking table.

### Using `booktabs` to produce the table

The gold standard for high quality tables is the `booktabs` package,  and `xtable` provides a boolean to do exactly that.

### Final R print command

```
print(xtable(summary(npk.aov)),floating=FALSE,latex.environments=NULL,booktabs=TRUE)
```

This produces the following, much nicer table: (you need to add `\usepackage{booktabs}` to the preamble of your LaTeX document.)

[image]

If you want the table to float, (because you are including it in a larger LaTeX document, the you should eliminate the `floating=FALSE` argument, and add `latex.environments=NULL)`.  In your LaTeX source, you will need to manually add `\centering` right after `\begin{table}` to center the table.

Comment: `print.xtable` now also has the `booktabs=` optional parameter that takes care of adding proper rules.

Answer (score 22):

Here is an alternative approach using the `latex` function from `Hmisc`.  On the one hand, it only does matrices and data frames; on the other hand, it natively knows about `booktabs`, is impressively tweakable either directly or via its subroutine `format.df`, and ships with the standard installation.  Using the same `npk.aov` example as Alan Munn did,  I can produce roughly the same table using

```
> latex(summary(npk.aov)[[1]], cdec=c(0,2,2,2,4), na.blank=TRUE,
        booktabs=TRUE, table.env=FALSE, center="none", file="", title="")
```

which outputs

```
% latex.default(summary(npk.aov)[[1]], cdec = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 4),      na.blank = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE, table.env = FALSE, center = "none",      file = "", title = "") 
%
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Df}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sum Sq}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean Sq}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{F value}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Pr(\textgreater F)}\tabularnewline
\midrule
block      &$ 5$&$343.29$&$ 68.66$&$ 4.45$&$0.0159$\tabularnewline
N          &$ 1$&$189.28$&$189.28$&$12.26$&$0.0044$\tabularnewline
P          &$ 1$&$  8.40$&$  8.40$&$ 0.54$&$0.4749$\tabularnewline
K          &$ 1$&$ 95.20$&$ 95.20$&$ 6.17$&$0.0288$\tabularnewline
N:P        &$ 1$&$ 21.28$&$ 21.28$&$ 1.38$&$0.2632$\tabularnewline
N:K        &$ 1$&$ 33.13$&$ 33.13$&$ 2.15$&$0.1686$\tabularnewline
P:K        &$ 1$&$  0.48$&$  0.48$&$ 0.03$&$0.8628$\tabularnewline
Residuals  &$12$&$185.29$&$ 15.44$&$$&$$\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

which renders very nearly the same as what Alan got:

[image: formatted table]

A possibly-significant change is that it wraps all the numbers in math mode, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: A great +1 for using `Hmisc` and showing how to use it in this particular context!

Comment: Thanks for your answer zwol. But I can't understand how to use example of Alan Munn for arbitrary data set?!

Answer (score 5):

An old question about how to use  R output in LaTeX and nobody mentions the old `Sweave` and the newer `knitr`?

Solution: You do not need to deal directly with the LaTeX chunk generated by R, just write a complete LaTeX document. As explained, this means start with ...

```
\documentclass{someclass}
 % maybe the next R and LaTeX  code will need some preamble here  
\begin{document} 
Some text ...
```

and end the document with, well ...

```
\end{document}
```

Now save it with the `.Rnw` (R noweb) extension, and inside it write the R code to generate that table delimited between two lines with `<<>>=` or `<<name, options>>=`  and `@`. The possible options vary if you use the R functions `Sweave` or the newer `Knitr` package to convert the `.Rnw` file into a true `.tex` file with/without the R output and/or with/without the R code depending of the options.  Finally, the `.tex` file is processed by  `pdflatex` or the TeX engine of your election to produce the `.pdf` file).

An easy way to do both file conversions is to edit the file with Rstudio  <kbd>Compile PDF</kbd> button while editing the `.Rnw` file.

Note: Avoid mix options of Knirt and Sweave (some are common but others are incompatible). As Knitr is newer and more powerful, at present my suggestion is to forget Sweave and focus on Knitr only.

Note: not only `xtable` package can do a LaTex table: at least you can use also  `knitr` itself, which has the `kable` function (with `kableExtra` could look also a decent table) as well as the packages  `stargazer` and `Hmisc`.

A little comparison in this little  `example.Rnw` file using `knitr`(*).

(*) You cannot compile this example "as is" with `Sweave` because some ot the R chunks options, as well as the `kable` function, are specific of `knitr`. Using Rstudio you can switch from using `Sweave` to `knitr` in  <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Global Options</kbd> > <kbd>Sweave</kbd> >  Weave Rnw files using: <kbd>Sweave</kbd> (change it to <kbd>knitr</kbd>).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1em,paperheight=8cm,paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,message=F,warning=F,comment="">>=
library(xtable)
library(stargazer)
library(kableExtra) 
library(Hmisc) 
data("mtcars")  # some example data 
df <-mtcars[1:3, 1:6]
@

<<echo=F,results="asis">>=
print(xtable(df,caption="Example with \\texttt{xtable}"), 
booktabs=T, caption.placement="top")
stargazer(df, summary=F, 
title="Example with \\texttt{stargazer}")
kable(df, booktabs = T, 
caption = "Example with  \\texttt{kable}  and \\texttt{kableExtra}")
latex(df, file = '', caption="Example with  \\texttt{Hmisc}")
@
\end{document}
```

Edit (2024):

Today, another possibility is Quarto. The idea is the same (R chunks among the text that are integrated with `Knitr`) but the text source is simple markdown (but that could include LaTeX code), the chunk syntax is different: The conversion process in this case is markdown with R chunks (.qmd) → just markdown (.md) → just LaTeX (.tex) → PDF. Example:

````
---
format: pdf
---

This will be also a \LaTeX{} document.

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| results: asis

data("mtcars") 
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:3, 1:6])

```
````

Note: Quarto is based on the older Rmarkdown, so is very similar,  but there are also some differences. Take care also of avoid mixing Rmarkdown and Quarto syntax. You can edit and compile Qurto documents  out of the box with Rstudio or VScode with the appropriate plugins or with any text editor and console commands.
[image: mwe]

Comment: Hi Fran, I got an error saying that the argument "asis" of results is not valid. It needs to be either of `verbatim`, `tex` or `hide`. Additionally there should be no quotes. I am using R 3.4.1. Could you confirm? Thank you!

Comment: @Ameya Sorry, I should have warned that the  example is specific for  `knitr`. I assumed that is was clear because show the  `kable` function (that need `knitr`) although the library is not loaded in the R chunks. The option "asis" or 'asis' is equivalent to `tex` using Sweave, but unfortunately not compatible.  If you are using Rstudio go to Tools > Global Options > Sweave >  Weave Rnw files using: `Sweave` > change it to `knitr`

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you. I am sorry, I am new to the RStudio environment for Latex.