# Automating Adding Tables Fast to LateX from R?

Tags: tables, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/how-can-i-use-a-table-generated-by-r-in-latex)

I use a lot of tables from R, and I find it cumbersome and very slow to type the "&" and "\" etc. to get the tables translated into LaTeX. Is there some way to have a table like that below automatically formatted for LaTeX?

```
      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                      74    1233.55
inflat  1     4.13        73    1229.42
inc     1   907.24        72     322.18
Analysis of Deviance Table

       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                      59    1450.07
inflat  1    99.44        58    1350.63
inc     1   861.93        57     488.69
Analysis of Deviance Table

       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                     158    28963.3
inflat  1   3302.4       157    25660.9
inc     1  23996.2       156     1664.8
```

Comment: You can use the R `xtable` package to generate LaTeX directly from R.  See [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575/2693)

Answer (score 2):

Using the XTable package as Alan commented.  There's a good set of example tables as part of the  [CRAN XTable vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf).  You may also want to look at the [descr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/descr) package which has helper function to produce some other usefull tables.

Xtable can either just produce the latex code that you can copy/paste into a tex file, or you can use it within a [sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) document to produce the tables automatically as part of your analysis.