# DB dump into LaTeX with Python and R?

Tags: indexing, r, database, python

I have quite a large index. I am planning to create a full-blown DB for it and later export the information to LaTeX. I am comfortable with R and Python so I would like to work with them but I feel there must be something already built. I mean to save info `INDEX_KEY|CATEGORY|TITLE|DESCRIPTION|TIME` in DB, rather than type that into latex directly - I feel DB could help with searching and indexing later. Do some DBs already have Latex converting possibility?

**Related**

1. [Postgress, Python and LaTeX -question](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2005-June/016183.html) (unsolved)
2. [Automating Adding Tables Fast to LateX from R?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34788/automating-adding-tables-fast-to-latex-from-r/35016) (maybe relevant)
3. [Using Python within LaTeX and accessing its variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33129/python-and-latex) (not yet tried, not sure whether relevant) outlining

Comment: IMHO you could use Python to read data from your DB and generate `mydata.tex` file with the entries already formated the way you want, e.g., using `longtable`, etc. Then in a main `tex` file, you just use `\input{mydata}`.

Answer (score 1):

I thik [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package is exactly whant you need.  From the package documentation:

> databases may be created using LaTeX commands or by importing external files; they may be sorted numerically or alphabetically; repetitive operations (such as mail merging) may be performed on each row of a database, subject to conditions to exclude particular rows; commands are provided to examine database elements, and to convert formats (for example, to convert a numeric element to a format compatible with the fp package;

Comment: It should be noted that **datatool** loads the entire database in memory, so it may not be the right tool to use if the DB is large.

Comment: @egreg: what would you suggest with massive db or scalable db (not to get any memory probs)?

Comment: @hhh Probably to get from the DB a suitably formatted file. TeX is able to read an entire file (`\input`) or to scan it line by line. **datatool** loads the file in the second way and transforms each line in a suitable way all inside LaTeX, which is memory consuming. Conversely, if the file is already conveniently formatted, it can be `\input`.