# side-by-side xtables in Sweave

Tags: sweave, r, xtable

I use `xtable` to manage my tables in `Sweave` like this

```
<<label=tab1, echo = FALSE, results = tex>>=
print(xtable(Table1))
@


<<label=tab2, echo = FALSE, results = tex>>=
print(xtable(Table2))
@
```

I wonder how to get these tables side by side. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic idea of this is that you need to make sure that the tables generated by `xtable` don't float; instead you should put them in your own floating environment.  In the example below, I've generated two side-by-side tables, each within a `{minipage}` environment and each with their own caption using the `\captionof` command of the `caption` package.

I've formatted the tables using `booktabs`.  See [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575/2693) for more details on this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\title{Side-by-side xtables}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
First some R code to create some data.
<<>>=
myData <- matrix(c(19,89,23,23,74,44,16,39,67),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(myData) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(myData) <- c("1","2","3")
myData2 <- myData * 2
@

Now we place the data in two side-by-side tables:

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library("xtable")
print(xtable(myData),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The first table}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
print(xtable(myData2),
  floating=FALSE,
  hline.after=NULL,
  add.to.row=list(pos=list(-1,0, nrow(myData2)),
  command=c('\\toprule\n','\\midrule\n','\\bottomrule\n')))
@
\captionof{table}{The second table}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. This works fine for small tables. I wonder how to use tabular.environment='longtable' for large tables. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to put two `longtable`s side by side independently of Sweave.  Because a `longtable` can break pages, you can put them beside each other.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Would you mind to tell me how to put Table captions above the table. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Just move the `\captionof` commands to right after the `\centering` command (before the code that generates the table).

Comment: BTW, in the comment about `longtable`s I meant to say because they can break pages you *can't* put them beside each other. (It was probably clear from the context anyway.)